Is the evolution of the universe reversible?
If unitary operators are reversible when applied to quantum states, and the universe is a closed quantum system where a unitary operation can describe its evolution, does this imply that the evolution of the universe is reversible?

I would say that would contradict some fundamental thermodynamic law, i.e. the second law of thermodynamics in some sense, but I hope someone can give a better detailed answer.

As long as no one observes it ...

Quantum mechanics is applied in microworld while the whole universe is macroworld. A think that the first step before answering your question is to reconcile quantum mechanics and general relativity to get a theory of quantum gravity. However, what you are describing is somehow similar to theory of big crunch. What is more, as @Zarathustra mentioned, there is a problem with second law of thermodynamics, and I would add that this also contradicts Hawking chronology protection hypothesis.

Just addition on big crunch. Even if this theory is true, there is no guarantee that events will take place in exact reverse order. This would be again in contradiction with the laws I mentioned in my previous comment.

How is this question related to quantum computing, broadly defined?
